# If the Earth is constantly accelerating at 9.8m/s^2, according to General Relativity, won't Earth's speed be constantly increasing towards infinity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, earth, solar-system

As per **Einstein's Theory of General Relativity**, I understand that 'the Earth's ground is accelerating towards us at 9.8m/s^2. This is why we're falling towards the center of the Earth, as GR doesn't accept gravity as a force'. So, if a car is supposed to accelerate constantly, at one point of time, it would reach its top speed. *Won't the same happen with Earth, as the top speed will be the speed of light?*
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you accelerate without moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265913/)

Comment: For more background see [If gravity isn't a force, then how are forces balanced in the real world?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392863/)

Comment: A useful notion here is coordinate acceleration. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333209/123208