Would weightlessness (i.e. in thrill rides, planes, skydiving, etc.) be different on a Flat Earth?
I was listening to a Scientific American podcast, dated March 27th, 2020, about what Flat Earthers believe and why they believe it. As I listened, Michael Marshall mentioned that FEers believe that the Earth is a plane which is accelerating upward at 9.8 m/s² (gravity 9.8 m/s² downward).
Scientifically, there is plenty of evidence (objects on the horizon or Eratosthenes' measurements) to disprove FEs' opinions, but if we are accelerating up, then wouldn't the experiences in a thrill ride be inverted or absent?
G-force is a mass specific force (force per unit mass). If you go on a thrill ride like the tower of terror and you drop, you experience a moment of weightlessness. If the Earth is accelerating upward, I shouldn't experience weightlessness. And the same for a tower ride which accelerates upward (you experience $g$-forces pulling you into your seat), but this would give you weightlessness (if 9.8 m/s² downward is true).
I am assuming that if the Earth were moving up according to the the FEs' opinion, then I would expect a sudden decrease in the upward force, because I am now accelerating at a different rate than the Earth. Wouldn't I feel heavier?
And I would think that all experiences in roller coasters, rockets, jet fighters, sky diving or even being in the "Vomit Comet" would be different.
Note - I've never been skydiving, but people tell me that you have the sensation of falling. I'm assuming that if the FEs' opinions were correct and the Earth accelerating upwards at 9.8 m/s², then I would be stationary while the Earth comes towards me. And with that, wouldn't parachutes not work? (edit) - Wouldn't skydivers need a jetpack rather than a parachute because they would need to match the upward acceleration of the Earth to land safely?

If the earth was flat then by a telescope we would be able to see a whole ship sailing on the ocean but we can only see its front part.How do flat earthers explain this?

Also the sky looks like a planetarium you can get the curvature of the Earth only by looking at the sky.

For the record I think this is a perfectly valid question - "if the Earth were flat (which it isn't), would the physics of thrill rides be different?" Would just like to say that for those who might close this because it contains the words "Flat Earth".

The main problem with FEs is that, regardless of what evidence you supply, they will construct arbitrary reasons to accommodate their belief.  The mere fact they require the entire Earth to be accelerating all the time for no apparent reason is so arbitrary that it should tell you logic is not really being applied here.  Physics and, by extension, Physics SE, is about real world physics.

I mean, it doesn't necessarily have to be about FE in specific. You could just as well ask if the physics of freefall (in-atmosphere) on an accelerating worldship-style rocket would be the same as on Earth. Still a little bit out there, but definitely within the realm of physics.

@StephenG but a planet under extreme conditions may not have a elliptical shape so this question is valid.

The equivalence principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle tells us that there is no way to distinguish between a uniform gravitational field and an accelerating frame of reference. So the physics of thrill rides and parachutes would be the same in both scenarios. There are, of course, many other ways to disprove the FE hypothesis.

"I've never been skydiving, but people tell me that you have the sensation of falling." I think you missed a "don't" - as soon as you're out of the plane, there is no sensation of falling. The sensation of falling is due to a change in acceleration, going from standing in the plane to accelerating downward at 9.8m/s^2 - it's the feeling of the "bottom dropping out". But as soon as you're in freefall, you do not continue to feel like you're falling.

@controlgroup Regarding the validity of the question, I suspect the negative attention is attracts isn't so much "hur dur flat urrth" as it is that there is no accepted consistent model of what a flat Earth represents, meaning that any answer can be countered by any arbitrary differently imagined interpretation of a flat Earth. However, those concerns put aside, OP is engaging in what I'm going to refer to as "flat Earther goalpost moving" exercises in response to the given answer (yours, actually), and that, in my opinion, does render the question meaningfully unanswerable.

@NuclearHoagie: There is a sensation of falling, because (a) the person is consciously aware that they're falling and (b) air resistance is altering their acceleration downward in a way that their body can sense. They can sense something and know they're falling, so they attribute the feeling to the notion of falling. Your comment would be correct for an astronaut in a space suit on a planet with no atmosphere, but the atmosphere is making a difference here.

@Flater The question itself is definitely pretty interesting, at least IMO.  But some of OPs comments do make me think it was posted to show as a "gotcha" to FEer's.  Which is funny to me because the "plane accelerating upwards" is quite possibly the most reasonable BS that FEer's use.  It's still wrong, but unlike most of their models, this one would actually accurately simulate the effects of gravity.

one interesting difference (that I don't think actually addresses the question itself) is that a flat earth accelerating upwards can only simulate a uniform gravitational field, whereas we actually see easily measurable differences in the value of g across the world (so much so that one of my first year labs measuring the value of g had to include a warning in the handbook that the local value was quite far from the "standard" value, as otherwise students would get bogged down trying to hunt for errors that weren't actually there)

@Flater I've been skydiving, and did not feel a sensation of falling after leaving the plane. The sensation is very well documented and described by countless sources, I can hardly find anything that describes it differently. You feel the wind slowing your acceleration, but it is nothing like the feeling from a roller coaster or tall diving board. Try it.

@NuclearHoagie How would it feel different from a diving board? Until you hit the water or release the parachute, they are physically identical in terms of forces you experience, the difference would be mostly visual cues.  Rollercoasters are a whole other beast IMO.  You get the sensations because you arent just free falling, you're being pushed around by the seat and whatever is keeping you strapped in.  I think that has more to do with switching between being pushed up by your seat, and being pushed down by the restraints.

@JMac Part of it is the duration - you do feel a drop the moment you step out of the plane, but the sensation disappears quickly. In a shorter fall off a diving board, you've hit the water by then. It's about the change from standing on firm ground to being in freefall that gives the falling feeling.

@JMac With the diving board and the like you never reach terminal velocity and thus you feel light.  In anything but a static line jump or the like you do--and once you are at terminal velocity your weight is normal.  At terminal velocity you need a great deal of fall arresting in order to walk away.  Living through hitting water at terminal velocity is possible but requires entering exactly right and keeping your wits about you well enough.  It rarely happens.

If we assume a flat disk sans gravity accelerating upwards at one $g$ (which is what the FEers propose), then the physics of thrill rides and parachutes and whatnot would actually be the same. If the disk is accelerating upwards, we should assume that its atmosphere is doing so as well, which means that even if you're stationary in some reference frame you still feel the sensation of air running past you faster and faster as you "fall".
The key aspect here is that this acceleration is, by definition in relativity, indistinguishable from gravitation. This is the result of the equivalence principle, which essentially equates inertial and gravitational mass. One of its consequences is that, in a box with no other information, you can't tell if you're on a rocket (or disk) accelerating at $9.81\,\mathrm{m}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2}$ or on Earth. In the case of a flat accelerating Earth, in the Earth's comoving reference frame (which is the one you're gonna want to work in) all objects appear to experience "gravitation" with "downward" acceleration at the exact same rate that in any inertial reference frame the disk is accelerating.
In reality you always experience weightlessness if you're not in direct contact with something that's putting a reaction force on your feet/back/etc. Falling from the sky, the only reason you feel anything but weightless is because of the air resisting your fall. If you were to go on a ride and briefly feel weightlessness, what that would mean is that the ride isn't accelerating you at all - this means that the Earth would be accelerating towards you at one $g$, which is equivalent to you accelerating towards the Earth at one $g$. In other words, weightlessness and related phenomena would still be the same.

You bring up interesting points, but parachutes work by slowing your descent to Earth. If I was a skydiver and FE's opinions are true, I would need a jet pack not a parachute. (edit) and we aren't in a box so there are variables to consider with the experience. We can't assume the atmosphere is also moving upwards. The force of the Earth moving upwards would drive the atmosphere in a different manner than it currently does (spinning sphere).

The air would still be rushing towards you and hitting the chute, slowing you down. I'm sure it would be aerodynamically different given that the air is constantly falling off of the FE, but from a kinematics point of view, the air and parachute don't care which is "in motion" and which isn't; that's the main tenet of relativity.

FE's do not believe that gravity exists in the manner which science currently explains. You would not be falling towards Earth. There is no force pulling you down.

In your comoving reference frame (without some external reference, like stars or the Sun or Moon or other planets), it is impossible to distinguish whether the Earth is accelerating "up" towards you via FE magic or if you are falling "down" towards Earth via gravity.

It's not impossible. Measuring the force of gravity at various locations on Earth, such as the Equator or the poles, as well areas which are closer to the core of the Earth or further way (trenches and mountain peaks).

If the Earth gravitates, sure. My point original comment meant that you can't distinguish whether a Flat Earth disk is accelerating up or if you're falling down, by simple relativity.

The website is telling me that I can not continue posting responses. My OP has nothing to do with "distinguishing whether a flat earth disk is accelerating up or if you are falling down". I reject your respoinse because it did not answer my OP.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@BeachBum: If you stand still on the ground, wearing an open parachute (for the purpose of example, it is being held in the air open, e.g. on hooks) and I aim a giant fan at your parachute, you will shoot upwards (relative to the ground). The parachute responds to the kinetic difference between it and the air it catches. Whether the parachute moves (because you fall towards Earth) and the air is still (relative to Earth); or the parachute is still (because you're standing on the ground) and the air moves (because of a massive fan); is an irrelevant distinction.

@BeachBum Stand on the hull of an airplane flying horizontally. Gravity has no bearing on this example, because it's perpendicular to what we're looking at. Open your parachute. What happens? From the perspective of someone standing on the plane with you, you will appear to change from standing still to suddenly shooting backwards. From the perspective of someone standing on the ground, you will appear to change from moving forwards to suddenly stopping moving. But both people will agree that the parachute had an effect on you. Parachutes work the same, flat Earth or no flat Earth.

@BeachBum "We can't assume the atmosphere is also moving upwards." If the atmosphere is not moving in tandem with the flat Earth, but the people are moving in tandem (because we can plainly see people standing still on the Earth's surface and no one is claiming that we're not), then the people would constantly feel a draft, expressed as the air (not moving with the flat Earth) moving differently than the people (moving with the flat Earth). You taking the artistic liberty to make the atmosphere static while the FE is not makes this an exercise in guessing what your imagination of a FE is.

While I agree that the free falling would cause the same sensation on an upwards moving disk or a rotating globe, the opposite is not true. If I start a rocket into orbit I would have to keep the thrusters going in the disk scenario in order not to be caught by the approaching disk again, but I can turn them off in the rotating globe scenario (because free falling around the globe; equilibrium of gravity by planet's mass and centrifugal force(= velocity on the orbit)).

If we assume a flat disk sans gravity accelerating upwards at one g, would that change how tides work? And how the moon would affect them? For a flat earth to maintain the seas I think FEers claim a ring of ice or a dome, assuming a pool or petri dish shape, what would happen to the water when accelerating upwards? I was thinking there'd be no tdes or that the water would gather at the edges but maybe not (Or is the disc also spinning?)

@controlgroup Air moving up past a stationary diver works the same.  We call them skydiving simulators (for training) or indoor skydiving (for sport.)

Suppose for a moment that you are inside a closed, airtight box, with no view ports. According to the equivalence principle, there is no experiment that you could do to decide whether your box was resting on the surface of the Earth, or sitting on a platform that was accelerating upward at a constant $9.8\,\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$. It would feel the same to you either way.
As for parachutes and airplanes and their like, So long as there were walls all around the edge of the disk of the flat Earth to contain the air (those walls would need to be at least $100\,\text{km}$ tall) flying and parachuting on the Flat Earth would feel no different from flying and parachuting on the actual, spherical Earth. The disk of the Earth would push the air upward with constant $9.8\,\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$ just the same as it would push upward on the soles of your feet.
Now, Buckle up! 'cause here's where it gets weird.
According to the theory of relativity, the surface of the Earth actually is accelerating outward from the center in all directions at $9.8\,\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$. That is to say, if you try to define an inertial coordinate system near the surface of the Earth, your coordinate system cannot be fixed to the Earth. An object in "free fall" would be stationary with respect to the "grid lines" of an inertial coordinate system, but we know that the same object, freely falling near the surface of the Earth, must be accelerating toward the surface at $9.8\,\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$. The explanation in general relativity is that the "grid lines" themselves are continually being sucked inward, and relative to those grid lines, the surface of the Earth must be seen as accelerating outward at $9.8\,\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$.
https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc

As an addendum: the one-$g$ acceleration away from the earth is an external force (specifically the reaction force from the ground) that counteracts the apparent acceleration due to geodesic curvature (gravity) to hold any object at rest on Earth’s surface.

@controlgroup, Agreed. When I talk to young'n's about gravity, I like to say that the feeling of gravity is the feeling of the ground pushing up on the soles of your feet (or, on your ass, depending on the audience) preventing you from falling all the way to the center of the Earth.

@SolomonSlow this also leads to a fun thing that people arguing against FEers (or geocentrists) often get wrong. They sometimes claim "if we're accelerating due to earth's rotation and orbit, why don't we feel a centrifugal force" and the answer is usually "it's too small to notice", which is right in one case (earth's rotation, it manifests as slight variation in $g$ with latitude) but wrong for the orbital one. Even in a tight orbit around a black hole, you wouldn't feel any centrifugal force, because you're just following a geodesic and not truly being acted on by a force.

@llama Almost. If it's a stellar-mass black hole (or neutron star) you really don't want to get into a tight orbit. The gradient in the field produces a strong tidal effect. Eg, a 1 metre long A36 steel bar in (vertical) freefall towards a 3 solar mass BH gets ruptured by the tension at ~110 km. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208

You assume correctly that there has to be walls around the disk to actually hold an atmosphere (of which I don't know if FEers think about such things). But the acceleration of the ground startles me. I could accept a counteracting force though, as controlgroup mentioned.

@vincentthacker, thank you for fixing my mistake.

@Antares, The math says that in a coordinate system that is attached to a freely falling object, it's the ground that is accelerating. Meanwhile,  if you attach accelerometers to the ground and to the falling object, the falling one will read zero, while the one on the ground reads one gee. Now, which one are you going to believe? Will you believe the math? Or will  you believe the experiment?

@SolomonSlow: The ground (=surface of the Earth) is not accelerating. It is moving. Acceleration would mean the planet expands, while moving means it comes closer. The whole planet moves towards the free falling object. Accelerated even, but not the surface alone in all directions. It is a matter of choice of words more than a mathematical one.

@SolomonSlow: I watched the video. I think the misconception comes from this: The acceleration to all sides is that what counters curved spacetime. But the objects (apple) inside the curved space time move due their time component. The earth is and is not expanding, because it is countered by the shrinking. So its radius stays constant all the time. The acceleration of objects inside the curved spacetime comes from the curvature, not from the earth accelerating towards it. This is only a way to imagine the two overlapping concepts of shrinking+expanding=stays constant.

@Antares Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766543/123208 (& links therein) on acceleration in GR, which explains how the Earth's surface is accelerating.

@PM2Ring sure, but at that point you're far far beyond where you'd naively expect to feel $1g$ of centrifugal acceleration (an orbit of 6 million km for that mass of BH)

Would weightlessness (i.e. in thrill rides, planes, skydiving, etc.) be different on a Flat Earth?
no
You might have heard "We can't actually feel speed. We can only feel acceleration and deceleration.", but while that is useful in the context of fx driving safety, it is not 100% correct/accurate. We can't strictly speaking feel acceleration/deceleration either. What we can feel is an external force acting/pressing upon us and causing acceleration/deceleration, but we cannot actually feel acceleration/deceleration by a uniform field (earths gravity field is practically uniform at the scale of a human).
Standing on earth with normal gravity (9.8 m/s²), you feel the normal force keeping you from accelerating further towards the center of the earth.
While standing on flat earth (without a gravity field but instead accelerating upwards at 9.8 m/s²) you would feel the force of earth pushing up towards you while your inertia is resisting the acceleration.
In both cases the force is the same, and the fluid in your inner ear will pool downwards giving you a clear sense of the direction down. It will feel identical.
Similarly in purely free fall without any reference you have no way to identify if you are in a gravity field or not, the fluid in your inner ear does not pool in any particular direction either way. So being in a gravity field accelerating you towards earth or being at constant speed with flat earth accelerating towards you will feel the exact same, weightless (i.e. the feeling of falling).
With skydiving, in addition to seeing the earth getting closer you also have the air rushing by you to add to your sense of direction, but whether you are accelerated through the air or the air is accelerated past you makes no difference to what you feel. In either case you will feel air resistance, so the fluid in your inner ear will pool and you will feel direction, but again it makes no difference if the fluid is pulled down or the rest of you is pushed up, it feels the same.

@Antares I am not sure what you mean. I agree with "The earth has a gravity field because of its mass and spherical form. The moving disc does not. It generates its g from moving upwards and is considered being massless (otherwise the gravity of the mass and the g by moving act in the same direction)." I don't see how it contradicts what I wrote?

@Antares yes that is what I meant. I think one way to get the idea from OP that we should feel a difference between the two cases, is if having the idea that we should feel the acceleration from the field that is only present in one of the two cases. I have edited my answer, hopefully it has made my intended point clearer.


I've never been skydiving, but people tell me that you have the sensation of falling.

The "sensation of falling" that you feel when jumping off a plane while skydiving (or bungee jumping or in an amusement park drop tower ride) is actually the sensation of (full or partial) weightlessness.
Humans have evolved to live on the surface of Earth, where we always feel an acceleration of 9.81 m/s² in some direction, depending on the orientation of our body.  That is, always except very briefly while jumping or falling.  Our inner ear senses both the direction and the magnitude of this acceleration, and when the magnitude suddenly drops (unexpectedly, or for longer than a typical jump off the ground would last), it triggers a reflexive physiological response similar to a fight-or-flight or startle response that alerts us to the fact that we're (probably) falling from high up and urgently need to either grab something or brace for impact.
It's the exact same sensation that astronauts feel when the rocket engine cuts out and they enter the free-fall part of their flight, or when training in a "vomit comet" aircraft.  The only difference is that those are pretty much the only situations where the sensation can last long enough for the brain to start acclimating to it.  Otherwise the feeling of weightlessness can only last a few seconds at most: even skydivers accelerate in about 10 seconds or so to close to their terminal velocity, i.e. the speed at which atmospheric drag becomes approximately equal to gravity and stops them from accelerating further.  At that point they no longer feel weightless, since their weight is now supported by onrushing air.

So what if, instead of the Earth's surface, you instead lived in a giant spaceship (big enough for amusement park rides or even skydiving) equipped with magic rocket engines that continuously accelerated the ship at a constant 9.81 m/s²?
In that case, you'd still experience a constant 9.81 m/s² acceleration, just as on Earth, and would thus feel your normal weight.  And if that acceleration ever temporarily stopped affecting you (e.g. because the engines turned off, or because you jumped off a platform), you'd still feel the "sensation of falling", just like on Earth.

While the Earth is spherical, its approximation by a flat surface accelerating upwards with magnitude $g$ is very good for all examples that you mention.
Whenever someone is in free fall, the surface accelerates to catch it, but before the impact there is no force acting on the body, so there is a weightless sensation.
All that problems of high school where it is said: consider the gravity acceleration constant equal to $9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}$, use implicitly that approximation.

The short answer is that there is not only no way to tell "gravity" from "acceleration" — it is actually the very same thing: Bent spacetime.
Things that would be different are:

The effects of the (real) Earth's curvature leading to different velocities of Earth's surface at different latitudes. Especially space flight and wind and sea currents are strongly influenced by those differences which are perceived as the Coriolis force.
The effects of the Earth's, Moon's and Sun's gravitational fields not being homogeneous leading to tides, different orbital mechanics and clock differences at different altitudes (but that won't convince your paranoid flat earther).


As an excursion, it is interesting to really fundamentally dissect the semantics of gravitational (or any other) acceleration.
For an observer resting in the approximate inertial system of the Earth's surface, a body falling in a vacuum in Earth's gravitational field is perceived as undergoing acceleration, by the famous $9.81 m/{s^2}$. However, from the body's perspective, that body is not accelerated at all; it is following a spacetime geodesic, entirely imperturbed by all external influences. It is, if you want, in its natural state, as long as it falls freely. You, the observer, by contrast, are kept from following your geodesic by electromagnetic interaction with the Earth's surface, you are suspended in a gravitational field: It is you who is accelerated out of its geodesic. All geodesics are created equal; all accelerations out of them by one of the non-gravitational forces are created equal as well. There is no difference.
(This makes clear that the sentence above introducing the observer was utterly wrong: the Earth's surface is emphatically not an inertial system, not even approximately. It is an accelerated system.)

The Earth is locally flat: if I want to travel to a place that is within a few miles of my house, I can use a flat map to navigate there. The round Earth model is needed only when I work at a larger scale. For example, if I go the the seashore and look towards the North Island, Te Ika a Maui, the curvature of the Earth causes the horizon to get in the way.
I don't think there is any simple purely local experiment that you can perform, e.g. going on a thrill ride, which will exhibit the Earth's curvature, unless you are seriously rich, i.e. rich enough to charter a space rocket.

What about a Foucault's Pendulum? One would have to explain away its weird behaviour.

@DavidTonhofer Good point, but surely Foucault's pendulum is concerned with rotation. The period does depend on the latitude, of course, but you need to perform the experiment at multiple locations to see that, so it is not a local effect. I've no doubt a spinning flat earther could some up with an ingenious (but stupid) explanation...

Of course there are differences.
Experiencing g on an upwards moving disk and experiencing g because moving upwards(=outwards) on a rotating, spherical surface, a globe, you are standing on and on which the gravitational pull of that mass counteracts that outward motion, is not logically equivalent.
The sensations are the same (and it is mathematically equivalent), but only as long as you are on the surface of either the disk or the globe. And you are not accelerating otherwise. Only free falling towards the surface of the disk feels the same as on the globe.
Also, it makes no sense that the disk should be moving upwards, if the disk is intended to have the same mass as the globe has. By moving upwards, the resulting gravity has the same direction (downward) as the gravitational force because of the mass has. Thus it would double the g force downwards. To make any sense, and assuming the disk has mass, this one has to fall/move downwards. This downward speed and the resulting accelerating force acting upwards together with the gravitational pull have to cancel each other out at 1g on the surface.
However, the following assumes the OP's stated scenario of a massless disk moving upwards in space and generating 1g at the surface.
The primary difference between both cases (disk vs. globe) is, that the disk only has one force to "simulate" gravity (moving upwards), while the globe has two (gravity and rotation/centrifugal acceleration).
Digging Holes
Imagine the disk being truly flat, of finite thickness and homogeneous mass distribution (but without weight). Now dig an imaginary hole downwards. Keep digging until you reach the other end. Because the disk is moving upwards you will experience the same 1g all the way down. Eventually you fall through the disk and end up being in weightlessness of space. The disk will continue its way without you.
Imagine the globe and dig a hole there. If you dig deeper you will experience a different g at increasing depths. You will feel lighter. At the center you experience total weightlessness and if you keep "digging down" you will experience increasing g again until it normalizes at the other side of the globe. You will continue staying on the globe.
You experience exactly one g only at the surface of the globe, because gravity from the mass of the planet and the rotational speed of the planet lift each other in a way that the gravitation towards the planet ends up 9.81 times higher than the centrifugal acceleration of the rotating planet also acting upon you.
Shooting Rockets into Orbit
If you imagine a rocket shot to orbit in a straight line upwards from the surface, this will also be different.
In the case of an upwards moving disk, there is no secondary force acting upon the rocket. As soon as you stop your thrusters, you will start "falling down" again (actually the disk is coming towards you), no matter on what orbit height you are.
In the case of the globe, this is different. At a certain orbit height you can deactivate your thrusters, because your centrifugal force (=velocity on that orbit) and the gravitation towards the planet have found another equilibrium to lift each other to almost 0. In this case, you are "free falling" around the globe all the time, without the need of external accelerations (=thrust).
Atmosphere
Atmosphere on a disk moving upwards in space will just be "compressed" and flow down at all sides. If the disk would be rotating, the atmosphere will be "spun off" to all sides as well.
On a globe this is different. The atmosphere is kept at the globe because every atom of it is subjected to the gravitational force towards the globe and its rotational force (centrifugal force) around its axis.
Acceleration
Imagine a Ferris wheel standing vertically, the seats are hanging free, always pointed down towards the ground. The wheel is spinning reasonable fast to let you feel force pushing you into the seat while spinning upwards. There is only one person (or a large mass) sitting in it which we focus here, there could be any number of persons.
On a flat disk moving upwards, you will experience the same sensation no matter where the wheel stands on the disk surface. You will feel more than 1g of weight when rising up and exactly 1g at the topmost point. Then you start free falling on the downward spin, feeling lighter, maybe weightless, depending on the spining velocity. At the lowest point you experience normal weight at 1g again and so forth.
On a globe this is different. If the Ferris wheel stands on the equator and is aligned with the globe's rotation, you are accelerated a little faster on the upward motion. If the wheel is aligned perpendicular to the globe's rotation the acceleration forces are similar to those on an upward moving disk (except there are small forces pressing you towards the side). On either pole those additional "catapulting" forces would not be experienced.

"By moving upwards, the resulting gravity has the same direction (downward) as the gravitational force because of the mass has." But this question is about the Flat Earther hypothesis that gravity is not caused by mass, it's purely due to acceleration.

@PM2Ring: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the hint! I have made it more clear that I follow the assumption of the OP. The thing with the disc having mass was just a try to maybe rectify things a little.

Oh, ok. Yes , the accelerating disk is only equivalent to a uniform gravitational field. It can't reproduce a field that varies across the surface of the Earth, or the tiny variations due to rotation. Or the vertical decrease in gravity due to the inverse square law. In particular, the escape velocity of a uniform field is infinite, and orbits don't make much sense, either. But Flat Earthers know that, so they generally reject orbits.
