What is the relationship between an object's surroundings and it being in free-fall?
I understand the general concept of an object being in free-fall, but I am still confused on some aspects.
What is the relationship between an object's surroundings and its being in free-fall? I understand that being in free-fall is when an object acts solely under the influence of gravity, but if you were the object, how would you know whether you are really in free-fall where your surroundings are acted upon by gravity along with you, or if your surroundings are just at equilibrium without any force of gravity acting at all?
In addition, my physics teacher mentioned that, without external information, we would not be able to tell that anything would have happened if the classroom turned upside-down and started accelerating in some random direction at g. I know this is related to the situation described above, but I can't quite put my finger on it yet.
I am very sorry if this is a silly question or a waste of time. I would simply like to learn as much as possible about these concepts!

Related: equivalence principle

This is far from a silly question. It is a question that Einstein pondered, which led to what he called the "happiest thought of his life" – the realization that locally, gravitational freefall is equivalent to no forces. And which led to General Relativity

You could use a spring accelerometer https://i.sstatic.net/QArsx.jpg which I borrowed from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/382382

It is one of the more surprising "inversions" of general relativity that what we clearly perceive as an accelerated movement (e.g., falling towards the Moon, or orbiting a planet) is actually being at rest from a relativistic standpoint (the trajectory is a geodesic); and that being what we perceive as being at rest, e.g. sitting in a chair, is actually being accelerated (we are kept from following a geodesic by external forces).

The relationship is weightlessness. If you are in your chair, you don’t push on it with your weight when you are in a free fall. That’s it. No long answers or differential equations are needed.

This related question may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766543/123208

Note that the term "free-fall" is used differently by laymen (from a physics "lens", it's misuse). For example: sky divers use free-fall to mean any part of the dive with nothing out, which ofc includes the terminal velocity phase.
We would call that "an object in motion tends to stay in motion if acted upon by no external force [lemma: or 2 or more forces that add to zero]".
So air resistance balances gravity and you fall at constant velocity (roughly, ofc the air is getting denser so you are slowing down--but we need some level of abstraction).
Regarding the edit that just appeared in the OP: "Is this a silly question?".
No, no it is not, and my qualitative answer is probably controversial, and a quantitative answer should require the major tools of General Relativity (GR).
Let's start out with just Newton: Free-fall is when the only external force acting on you ($m$) is:
$$ \vec F = -G\frac{Mm}{r^2} \hat r $$
You can determine this is the case experimentally by using an accelerometer:

If all 3-axises measure ZERO, you are in basic Newtonian free-fall.
A skydiver before air takes effect, ISS astronauts (esp. on EVA), the Vomit Comet:


or the classic: theoretical physicists in a broken elevator,

those are all standard "free-fall" scenarios. I was going to say.  "If your trajectory is the ballistic trajectory, you are in free-fall", but the internet says "ballistic" includes drag and Magnus effect and all that--so you need to be careful!
Fortunately, the tools of physics (math) provide us with an unambiguous method to determine "free-fall". That tool is the Geodesic Equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity):
$$ \frac{d^2x^{\mu}}{ds^2}
+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}
\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{ds}
\frac{dx^{\beta}}{ds}
=0
$$
If your motion (along a path $x^{\mu}(s)$) in space-time is a solution of that equation, you are in free-fall.
It's a fantastic equation. It says you acceleration (plus some 4-velocity product with curvature) is zero.
In "space" (out there in flat Minkowski space time, with no gravity), it just says there is no acceleration, which is Newton's law.
Near a massive ($M$) spherical body, only the radial coordinate is non trivial, and the equation reads:
$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -G\frac{M}{r^2} $$
That is, free-fall means accelerating downward at (Here, on Earth, at the surface):
$$ g = -G\frac{M_{\oplus}}{R_{\oplus}^2} = -9.82\,{\rm m/s^2} $$
It's a nice result, and the details are elsewhere on this site [todo: link].
In short: I think it is safe to say, that in free-fall, you have zero acceleration [in the right coordinates]. (However, gravity is non-linear, and I am reticent to make broad sweeping statements when:
$$ R \gg \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$
is violated.
Regarding my comment "in the right coordinates". Coordinates are a big deal. Even for the sky-diver falling ($\vec v$), the Earth ($M_{\oplus}$) is spinning ($\Omega_{\oplus}$)), and you will find that Newton:
$$ \vec F =-G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\hat r $$
doesn't quite work out. There is a centrifugal term:
$$ \vec F_c = -m\Big(\Omega_{\oplus}
\times (\Omega_{\oplus} \times r)\Big)
$$
and possiblly a non-zero Coriolis term:
$$ \vec F_C = -2m\Omega_{\oplus}\times \vec v$$
Note that these are so-called inertial forces (proportional to $m$). Some people call them "fictitious forces" because they depend on the choice of coordinates.
I consider them part of "gravitation", and are a required component of defining "free-fall".
The mathematical physicist can tell you General Relativity can be explained as follows: "Physical laws are covariant under coordinate diffeomorphisms", which in English means: "Physics doesn't care about your coordinate system". (This is a major rabbit-hole, and I am going to exit it now).
For us, it means that if you move along a geodesic, you are in free-fall and your accelerometers will all measure ZERO. Other observers may see you accelerating, but when they work out the effects "gravitation" (i.e., Newton's gravity plus fictitious forces, and they include gravio-electromagnetism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism)), those are the only external forces acting on you, and that is "free-fall".

Nice answer. However, I think that some mention of the non-local effects of gravitation (tidal effects) should be made to answer the main question about the difference between free-fall in the presence of gravitation and the absence of any interaction.

While the first answer seems fairly comprehensive in terms of the physics and is both well-written and coherent, I'll add a few thoughts that may help a little with the intuitive side of things. Both special and general relativity are notoriously slippery beasts, and even working physicists commonly make mistakes when interpreting the theory's equations to the real world. You only have to look at the multitude of different ways that Einstein's so-called "Twins Paradox" is answered by various high-profile physicists over on YouTube to see that.
Another thing about gravity that distorts our view of it is that we're all taught, essentially from the moment that we can stand up by ourselves, that when we or other objects around us fall, this is due to gravity. It isn't. An insect can easily defeat the entire gravitational pull of the planet simply by beating its wings, and if you were to push a pen off your desk then it would take around 3 hours before gravity drew it down to rest on the ground. We, and everything around us, remain stuck to the surface of the Earth because the planet's internal pressure naturally pushes the surface up and out into space at the rate of 9.8 m/s². When you "fall", it isn't you that is plummeting down to Earth; it is the Earth that is accelerating up towards you!
This is why any two objects, no matter their size or mass, always appear to fall at exactly the same rate; because when you let them go they don't move anywhere in space. And it is the Earth that rushes up to meet them again, so of course, they will come into contact with the ground at the same time; how could they not?
Similarly, if you imagine jumping off the top of an impossibly high skyscraper, then (forgetting air resistance), you could pour yourself a drink, take a sip, and then place the glass next to yourself without any difficulty whatsoever, and the glass would stay exactly where you'd placed it, too. Because neither yourself nor the glass would be moving anywhere, the windows of the skyscraper would be rushing up past you, not you rushing down past them!
Once you have this essential picture of what's going on then it makes everything else much more simple to interpret. You are quite correct to say that a freely falling, or inertial,  body is one that is only acted upon by gravity, but...
...the main thing you should know about gravity is that, as I'm sure you've heard before, it is not a force. And because it isn't a force you can't feel it acting on you. Despite the enormous amount of gravity created by a supermassive black hole, if you were to find yourself falling through the event horizon of the one at the centre of our galaxy, then you wouldn't notice anything untoward about the experience at all.
The second thing to know about gravity is that it always acts on everything, even massless particles like photons. And it acts on them, somewhat paradoxically, because it is not a force. Gravity is the effect of living in a curved spacetime, and not of a force operating upon your mass. So, in answer to your question, it simply wouldn't be possible for the objects in your environment to not be as affected by gravity as you were.
That said, though, if you were out in interstellar space and confined to a windowless box, then there would be no experiment that you could conduct to establish whether or not you were at rest on the surface of the Earth, or whether you were being accelerated upwards by a rocket ship with your box in tow. This is Einstein's equivalence principle; in a small region of spacetime, the effect of gravity is indistinguishable from acceleration.
Anyway, I hope this helps you a little bit!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I assume you're talking about coordinate acceleration, but I feel that parts of this answer may be misleading.

"if you were to push a pen off your desk then it would take around 3 hours before gravity drew it down to rest on the ground." How does that work? It appears to disagree with common observation...
